# How to get docker-compose to always re-create containers from fresh images?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker images are built on a Jenkins CI server and are pushed to our private Docker Registry. My goal is to provision environments with docker-compose which always start the originally built state of the images.

I am currently using docker-compose 1.3.2 as well as 1.4.0 on different machines but we also used older versions previously.

I always used the `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d` commands to fetch the fresh images from the registry and start them up. I believe my preferred behaviour was working as expected up to a certain point in time, but since then `docker-compose up` started to re-run previously stopped containers instead of starting the originally built images every time.

Is there a way to get rid of this behaviour? Could that way be one which is wired in the docker-compose.yml configuration file to not depend "not forgetting" something on the command line upon every invocation?

ps. Besides finding a way to achieve my goal, I would also love to know a bit more about the background of this behaviour. I think the basic idea of Docker is to build an immutable infrastructure. The current behaviour of docker-compose just seem to plain clash with this approach.. or do I miss some points here?

Comment: `docker system prune -a`

Answer (score 448, accepted):

`docker-compose up --force-recreate` is one option, but if you're using it for CI, I would start the build with `docker-compose rm -f` to stop and remove the containers and volumes (then follow it with pull and up).

This is what I use:

```
docker-compose rm -f
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up --build -d
# Run some tests
./tests
docker-compose stop -t 1
```

The reason containers are recreated is to preserve any data volumes that might be used (and it also happens to make `up` a lot faster).

If you're doing CI you don't want that, so just removing everything should get you want you want.

Update: use `up --build` which was added in `docker-compose` 1.7

Comment: Yeah, actually this is what I do in CI as well. Not sure why I didn't mention that...

Comment: @dnephin `docker-compose run -d` doesn't exists ? You want to say `docker-compose up -d` no ?

Comment: if you run ```docker-compose pull``` before ```docker-compose rm -f``` you can save even more time

Comment: `rm` removes containers, and `pull` pulls images. I don't see how that would save more time. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: What is the the -d flag at the end do?

Comment: "-d     Detached mode: Run containers in the background,"

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that is you are using a Dockerfile then you may need to build with the `--pull` option as the `docker-compose pull` command will not do this. So there may be another step running `docker-compose build --no-cache --pull` and then simply `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: This did not work in Mac OS.

Answer (score 442):

The only solution that worked for me was the `--no-cache` flag:

```shell
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

This will automatically pull a fresh image from the repo. It also won't use the cached version that is prebuilt with any parameters you've been using before.

Comment: In addition, under Windows 10 it can help to set the DNS server in the settings from Automatic to Fixed or from Fixed to Automatic.

Comment: Worked for me on OS X building with docker-comopse version 2.

Comment: Worked on OS X docker.

Comment: This worked for me in Mac OS as well. The accepted answer did not.

Comment: This does not work in docker-compose 1.29.2.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you can append your service's name after the "--no-cache" parameter to only build that specific service

Answer (score 147):

By current official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) there is a shortcut that stops and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up, if they are already stopped or partially removed and so on, then it will do the trick too:

```
docker-compose down
```

Then if you have new changes on your images or Dockerfiles use:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Finally:`docker-compose up`

In one command: `docker-compose down && docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up`

Comment: `docker-compose build --no-cache` is needed only if there are changes on Dockerfiles.

Comment: Indeed, Victor. Thanks! I thought that it was also necessary after updating a module/application that is executed when the container starts up.
For these cases, before running `docker-compose up`, is necessary  to rebuild the services with `docker-compose build`.

Comment: We should mention the service name otherwise all the services will start to re-build from the beginning.

Comment: What kind of cache is used to build the image?

Answer (score 75):

```
docker-compose up --build  # still use image cache
```

OR

```
docker-compose build --no-cache  # never use cache
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: Actually this answer was the most clean and clear to me.

Comment: My understanding is that the --build command rebuilds, but uses cached parts, and thus not fully "recreates" the containers. Only the second does what I want.

Comment: Doesnt work on docker on centos 7, had to rm -rf /var/lib/docker

Comment: Two commands are completely different!
`docker-compose up --build` uses cache images if it is exist.
`docker-compose build --no-cache` never uses cache.

Comment: `build --no-cache` is the one

Answer (score 40):

You can pass `--force-recreate` to `docker compose up`, which should use fresh containers.

I think the reasoning behind reusing containers is to preserve any changes during development. Note that Compose does something similar with volumes, which will also persist between container recreation (a recreated container will attach to its predecessor's volumes). This can be helpful, for example, if you have a Redis container used as a cache and you don't want to lose the cache each time you make a small change. At other times it's just confusing.

I don't believe there is any way you can force this from the Compose file.

Arguably it does clash with immutable infrastructure principles. The counter-argument is probably that you don't use Compose in production (yet). Also, I'm not sure I agree that immutable infra is the basic idea of Docker, although it's certainly a good use case/selling point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it would be really useful to force it at the configuration level, eg. to enforce it for a database container and disable recreation by default for the app containers..

Comment: `--force-recreate` doesn't work for me ... Image is not pulled even though a newer version is out there...

Comment: @lisak I never said it pulled new images. It doesn't. It just starts new containers using whatever image is locally available. You'll need to run docker pull manually.

Answer (score 9):

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

Comment: With what version of docker compose this command works?

Comment: @lubrum any recent one

Answer (score 6):

I claimed 3.5gb space in ubuntu AWS through this.

clean docker

> docker stop $(docker ps -qa) && docker system prune -af --volumes

build again

> docker build .
>
> docker-compose build
>
> docker-compose up

Answer (score 6):

together with `--force-recreate`,
you might want to consider using this flag too:

```
 -V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
                            data from the previous containers.
```

I'm not sure from which version this flag is available, so check your `docker-compose up --help` if you have it or not

Answer (score 4):

Also if the compose has several services and we only want to force build one of those:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache <service>
```

Comment: This does not work in docker-compose 1.29.2.

Answer (score 3):

For me in Gitlab-ci when I deployed the project to the server, it has needed to run `docker-compose down`, then `docker system prune` for removing caches and again run `docker-compose up -d`.

But I've just added `docker-compose up --force-recreate` and it did all of the above commands together. iI worked for me!

Answer (score -22):

```
$docker-compose build
```

If there is something new it will be rebuilt.