# Docker: Uses an image, skipping (docker-compose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am currently trying out this tutorial for `node express` with `mongodb`
https://medium.com/@sunnykay/docker-development-workflow-node-express-mongo-4bb3b1f7eb1e

the first part works fine where to build the `docker-compose.yml`
it works totally fine building it locally so I tried to tag it and push into my `dockerhub` to learn and try more.

this is originally what's in the `yml` file followed by the tutorial

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

this works like a charm when I use `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`

so I tried to push it to my dockerhub and I also tag it as `node-test`

I then changed the `yml` file into

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: "et4891/node-test"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

then I removed all images I have previously to make sure this also works...but when I run `docker-compose build`  I see this message `error: web uses an image, skipping` and nothing happens.

I tried googling the error but nothing much I can find.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: „Your“ dockerhub? Please clarify: your own registry or your account on docker.io

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg `https://hub.docker.com/` this place...

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=et4891&starCount=0

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yes, also the same happend to lab4.1 which works perfectly in school today.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I found out, I was being stupid.

I didn't need to run `docker-compose build` I can just directly run `docker-compose up` since then it'll pull the images down, the `build` is just to build locally

Comment: It might be worth expanding a bit on it: if instead of `build` (which you can only do by pointing to specific `Dockerfile`) you use `image` then there is nothing to build because you directly use image from docker repository.

Comment: If the image is built locally, then need steps like this:
`docker build -t <image name> <directory>` to build locally, `docker-compose up -d  <service name>` to recreate container and start it.

Answer (score 43):

in my case below command worked:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: But this is UP, not BUILD. Didn't op want to build?

Comment: THis is to recreate the container with any changes, so similiar with build

Answer (score 37):

**Clarification:** This message (`<service> uses an image, skipping`)
is NOT an error. It's informing the user that **the service uses *Image* and it's therefore pre-built**, So it's skipped by the build command.

In other words - You don't need build , you need to `up` the service.

**Solution:**

run `sudo docker-compose up <your-service>`

*PS*: In case you changed some configuration on your docker-compose use `--force-recreate` flag to apply the changes and creating it again.

```
sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate <your-service>
```

Answer (score 8):

My problem was that I wanted to upgrade the `image` so I tried to use:

- `docker build --no-cache`
- `docker-compose up --force-recreate`
- `docker-compose up --build`

None of which rebuild the image.

What is missing ( from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127792/448831) ) is:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose rm -f # remove old images
docker-compose pull  # download new images
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was missing the `build` section in `docker-compose.yml` file, which resulted in exactly the same message being printed:

```
abc_service uses an image, skipping
```

The solution was to add the missing `build` section, e.g.:

```
  abc_service:
    image: abc_service-1.0.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/abc_service/Dockerfile
```

This answer basically expands the comment from @jean-darme