# Docker pull - force download

Tags: docker

Is there a possibility to force pull of docker image?

I have redeployed docker image to another repository, but when I invoke

```
docker pull anotherrepo:port/my/image
```

nothing gets downloaded, instead I get info:

```
Digest: sha256:somehash
```

and that image is up to date.

docker rm/rmi doesn't work because the image is downloaded from originalrepo:port/my/image and I don't want to stop/delete it onyl for test purposes.

Is there possible to force pull to check if the image is correctly pushed?

Comment: You can remove old image using docker rmi <your_image_id> and try. it will re download whole image though.

Comment: docker rm and then docker pull

Comment: Can you provide full log for `docker pull`

Answer (score 15):

The following should work. You add a temporary tag to avoid deletion of the image, delete the original tag and then pull:

```
docker tag "$originalTag" "tmpTag"
docker rmi "$originalTag"
docker pull "$originalTag"
docker rmi "tmpTag"
```

Comment: i think OP like me is thinking of a simple flag in `docker pull` that can allow this. Of course removing the image with `docker rmi` would work but what about a way to always force retrieval of the latest, something like always pull image in Kubernetes.

Comment: For docker build, you can do `docker build --pull` to force the re-download each time it is built. There is no such option currently for `docker run` and `docker pull`.

Comment: why need to tag it tmpTag first?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker Compose, a "docker compose pull" will automatically do what you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127792/1747140

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in digests.

> Images that use the v2 or later format have a content-addressable identifier called a digest. As long as the input used to generate the image is unchanged, the digest value is predictable.

Source:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-the-full-length-image-ids

Maybe you don't need to verify if the push was successful, as Docker could be doing that automatically by using digests, but I'm not sure if this is indeed the case.

The only other way I can think of would be to pull from a different machine which has access to the new repository.