# Docker container without last image version

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm facing a problem on my production server with a container that contains the `latest` version of the image but when I'm executing it, the content is not the last one.

To update docker images, I execute a little script with theses commands

```
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
docker-compose prune -fa
```

Of course, the image used in the docker service is with the `latest` tag

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/api:latest
```

Here is two screenshots with the **container** and the **image** content to see the differences

[image: Container content]

[image: Image content]

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=com@xxxxx.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--pilot.token=xxxxx"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      # dashboard
      - "traefik.http.routers.monitor.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.monitor.rule=Host(`monitor.xxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.monitor.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.monitor.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

  api:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/api:latest
    ports:
      - 4200:8080
    volumes:
      - api-data:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`api.xxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  front:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/front:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.front.rule=Host(`dev.xxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.front.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.front.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  panel:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/panel:latest
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    depends_on:
      - api
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.panel.rule=Host(`admin.xxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.panel.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.panel.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  coming-soon:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/coming-soon:latest
    ports:
      - 3002:3000
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.coming-soon.rule=Host(`xxxxx.com`) || Host(`www.xxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.coming-soon.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.coming-soon.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    volumes:
      - adminer-data:/root/.pgadmin
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.adminer.rule=Host(`adminer.xxxxx.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.adminer.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.adminer.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 4
        delay: 30s

volumes:
  db-data:
  api-data:
  adminer-data:
```

Comment: Please show your docker compose file

Comment: Added it to the question

Comment: How do you build the image?

Comment: I'm building images using the gitlab-ci

Comment: And you always build it without tag or with the latest tag?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685581/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-use-the-latest-image-from-repository

Comment: I'm building it with the `container_image` tag with AND the same with the `latest` tag, as you can see the image with the latest tag is correct. The problem is that it's not the correct version in the container.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski this question is not helping me. I'm using images already built, executing `docker-compose build -pull doesn't work for me.

Comment: you need stop the containers and clean the environment with `rm`. If still you are not pulling the images, try to remove the image explicitly (`docker image rm`) or add the policy `pull_policy: always` do the docker-compose file.

Comment: I tried to do `docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d` and the problem is still here. Removing the image is useless, it's the good one with the right version, the problem is with the container.

Comment: Did you try tag your image not latest as v1 or v2 etc. Also use `docker-compose up --force-recreate ` to create with no cache.

Comment: Yes I tried to use the specific tag instead of the latest but the problem is the same even with the flag to recreate containers