# Access docker-compose api from outside host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to deploy an application using `docker-compose` inside an EC2 host.

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, one of the services will use a constant docker tag, as in `myrepo/myimage:stable`.

Periodically, the image will be updated (same tag, different `hash`) so I will need to [run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39127792/2409793) `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d`.

My question is whether there is a way of exposing `docker-compose`'s API so that this can be invoked using an api call to the EC2 instance so as to avoid having to ssh into the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Compose doesn't have an API *per se*, it is just a local command-line tool.  You need to use something like ssh, or a generic system-automation tool like Ansible or Salt Stack, to invoke it.

Amazon's hosted container-cluster systems do have network-accessible APIs.  If you use EKS, you can use the Kubernetes API to update a Deployment spec's `image:`.  Amazon's proprietary ECS system has a different API, but again you can use it to remotely update the image name without having direct access to the underlying node(s).

---

In all cases you will be better off if you can use a unique tag per build.  In a Compose setup you could supply this via an environment variable

```yaml
image: myrepo/myimage:${TAG:-stable}
```

and then deploy it with

```sh
ssh root@remote-host TAG=20210414 docker-compose up -d
```

Since each build would have a distinct tag/name, you don't need to explicitly `docker-compose pull`; Docker will know to pull an image that it doesn't already have locally.

In a Kubernetes/EKS context in particular, it's important that the `image:` value changes to force an update (or downgrade!); if you tell Kubernetes that you want to run a Pod with the `stable` tag, and it already has one, it won't change anything.

Comment: Thanks; even in the case of distinct tags however I do have to update (somehow) my `docker-compose.yaml` file to pass in the new tag, right?