# docker-compose build image parameters --force-rm --pull

Tags: docker-compose

Usually I building my docker images like this:
`docker build -f Dockerfile.example" -t private/box --force-rm --pull .`
Because I'm using docker compose, I've decided to setup building in **docker-compose.yaml**:

```
build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: "Dockerfile.example"
```

But how can I add `--force-rm --pull` parameters there? Didn't find any examples.

Comment: I think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-start-fresh-images

Comment: thanks, I know it and use, but that is not what I exactly want.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to perform this in one docker-compose command