# How do I restart a Docker container/image/machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm trying to teach myself about Docker and using the docker-compose.yml to play around with images and the compose file. I've got the Wordpress image up and running using successfully `docker-compose.yml up -d` via the tutorial here... https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/), but as soon as I make changes to the compose file and `docker-compose.yml up -d` again I can't access the changes again and have to completely delete images/containers/docker machine's to get my changes to work.

What am I doing wrong, what's the process to restart/delete the minimum amount to see my docker-compose.yml changes so I can play around with docker-compose.yml?

Comment: would http://stackoverflow.com/a/32618288/6309 help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose stop` to stop the stack
`docker-compose start` to start the stack

Both above will not remove your container, but rather shutdown and start them again, without any loses, even on the container filesystem, not only the volumes

`docker-compose down` will remove the containers of your services and all anonymous volumes assigned to them.

Be aware, not all changes in the docker-compose file can be applied using start/stop, rather most of the time, you have to do a down/up. Things like volumes/ports cannot be hot-applied like this.

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't strictly what resolved it, but helped hugely in solving the issue. I was changing the port to 6000 (instead of 5000) and it turns out 6000 is reserved or does not work on Mac (at least). Any other port seems to work.