# docker-compose run not last image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml pull
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate
```

I have not last image - seems like this some cached image from first run.
But wen I run this image from docker via name, like
`docker run -it repo_url/image_name` 
- all ok.
I have try all from topic
[How to get docker-compose to always re-create containers from fresh images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-start-fresh-images)
Also I have try remove this image via `docker rmi image_name`, but nothing help to me. What it can be?

Comment: What is the content of the compose file ? Maybe there is a specific version of your image specified in it.

Comment: php:
    image: registry.url/content-php:latest
    links:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - datadir:/var/www/html/

Comment: It should use the latest version. Are you sure the containers are effectively recreated ? You can try to delete the containers manually and it should use the latest version of the image when you start `docker-compose up`.

Comment: yes, I already try
`docker-compose pull
docker-compose kill
docker-compose rm -f
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`
but no effect

Comment: Is your new image shipping new content in the folder `/var/www/html/` ? If this is the case this will not be reflected when you recreate the container because the volume will not be recreated. EDIT : You can try `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down --rmi all -v` which will stop and remove the containers, images and volumes

Comment: You my hero! This help to me!

Comment: I really use ADD . /var/www/html in my dokerfile. 
but for other images I newer see something like this before

Comment: this problem relevant only for /var/www/html/ or for all folders?
and Paul, please post you answer as comment, I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: You should edit your question a bit with the informations in the comments (like the volumes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What is happening

### Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:latest
COPY index.html /var/www/html/
```

1. You run it with a volume : `docker run -v my-data:/var/www/html/` since this volume does not exist yet it is created and the content of /var/www/html **from the current image** is copied into it.
2. Then you change the file index.html and rebuild your image. A new image is now created.
3. You run it with the same command. The volume my-data exist so the content of /var/www/html from **this new image** you just created will **not** be copied into the volume.
4. So when you access the front page you will see the old file.