# Testing Django app with docker compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to start my Django application. I am having problems keeping the data volumes between development and test separated. The development version of the code looks like this, and has data stored in Postgres, Elasticsearch, and Redis:

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.6
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
    volumes:
       - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.6
    volumes:
       - redis-data:/data

  redis_cache:
    image: redis:3.2.6

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:5.6.6
    volumes:
       - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:example@db/postgres
    - ENVIRONMENT=development
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    - REDIS_CACHE_URL=redis://redis_cache:6379
    - ELASTIC_ENDPOINT=elasticsearch:9200
    env_file: docker.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - redis_cache
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - .:/code

volumes:
  pg-data: {}
  redis-data: {}
  elasticsearch-data: {}
```

I created another version of this document for testing the app, which is called docker-compose.test.yml. Each time I start this version of the app I want to use a fresh copy of Postgres, Elasticsearch, etc. But it does not work that way. The goal is to populate some data during the test, then have it all removed on shutdown.

I thought I could simply start services without a named volume to accomplish this. Like so:

```
 db:
    image: postgres:9.6.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
```

Then I ran the test with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run --rm web python manage.py test --verbosity=2
```

But what I noticed is the tests are referring to the same data that is the named volume pg-data. So I do not have a fresh copy of the database. I did not expect that behavior. I can name the volumes something different in the test version of docker-compose, like pg-test-data, but then they will persist after running the tests and need to be manually removed.

So what is the proper solution for an issue like this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-re-create-containers-from-fresh-images

Comment: Hmm yes seems like the same issue. But using docker-compose up in the proposed solution would turn running tests into 5 commands rather than 1. I'm also nervous it would delete the development data.

Comment: Can you remove the volume so that the data is written into the container?