# How to clear my prior docker projects from my system?

Tags: docker

In my kubuntu 18.04 I tried some docker projects, so now running command

```
docker images
```

I see big listing of some my prior projects I started several months ago.
1) Which is the valid way to delete some of these projects at all?

2) Which is the valid way to clear the current project as I want running

```
 docker-compose up -d
```

3) command to regenerate my project fully?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images) 2,3) is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-re-create-containers-from-fresh-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a total cleanup: docker system prune
For a more measured approach: docker rm  docker rmi

docker-compose down  docker-compose rm take care of a docker compose project.