# How to change mongodb password in docker compose

Tags: mongodb, authentication, docker-compose

I tried to change the mongodb password in docker-compose.yaml file directly by changing the `- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` parameter within environment in mongodb service.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file before changing the password:

```
mongo-dev:
 container_name: mongo-dev
 image: mongo
 restart: unless-stopped
 environment:
  - AUTH=yes
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=old-pass
 volumes:
  - /data/mongodb-dev:/data/db
 ports:
  - 27017:27017
```

I changed `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` value from "old-pass" to "new-pass" and used `docker-compose up -d` command to re-create mongodb container:

```
mongo-dev:
 container_name: mongo-dev
 image: mongo
 restart: unless-stopped
 environment:
  - AUTH=yes
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=new-pass
 volumes:
  - /data/mongodb-dev:/data/db
 ports:
  - 27017:27017
```

And when i tried to connect to DB with "new-pass" as password i got authentication error but it still connecting to mongodb container with "old-pass".

It seems to me that changing the `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` in docker-compose file does not apply password changing in mongodb container.

Comment: Run `docker-compose build --no-cache` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-re-create-containers-from-fresh-images

Comment: i tried that but still have same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the correct way to change mongodb password.
These following steps will help:

- enter to mongo container bash by `docker exec -it mongo-dev bash`
- enter `mongo admin -u root -p old-pass` command for authentication and enter to mongo shell
- use admin db by `use admin`
- enter `db.changeUserPassword("root", "new-pass")` command to change password

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned the below property and due to this property, it is not picking your new password:

```
restart: unless-stopped
```

To ensure that the changes take effect, you need to stop the container using

```
docker-compose down
```

and then start it again using

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but it did not work and i found out using `db.changeUserPassword("username", "newPassword")` will work.