# Docker: remove all layers of one particular image

Tags: docker

I am developing a number of projects in parallel. All of them are run on Docker. Therefore I've got a lot of images that belong to different projects.

One project build went wrong. It used the wrong base image. In order to rebuild the project completely I would have used docker-compose --no-cache in past times, only this doesn't work any more. So what do I use now? I need to get rid of the intermediate layers.

Using docker system prune --all is definitely *not* the way to go, as I then will have to spend very considerable time to get all the images back that I didn't want to delete in the first place.

I know there is system prune --filter, and I have a way of filtering for the right images based on a label, but the images aren't dangling, so this deletes nothing.

I could imagine that system prune --all --filter is what I want, but I'm absolutely scared of using it as there's no dry-running it.

Can anybody help?

(The question referred to in [How to get docker-compose to always re-create containers from fresh images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-re-create-containers-from-fresh-images) mentioned in AymDev's comment is about recreating *containers* from images instead of rebuilding *images* from scratch, so unfortunately it doesn't help me.)

Comment: Why do you say that `--no-cache` doesn't work?  Note that if you change the base image   in a Dockerfile, the cache of the previous build cannot be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get docker-compose to always re-create containers from fresh images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612650/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-always-re-create-containers-from-fresh-images)

Comment: @Pino I tried, and it still used cached layers. The point is that `docker-compose`(with the hyphen) is very outdated and deprecated. It has been superseded by `docker compose` (no hyphen), and `docker compose` has no option --no-cache. I tried calling `docker-compose`as it's still installed on my machine, but it doesn't work properly any more.

Comment: @AymDev Hm, I'm talking about building. I want to build and then push to dockerhub. I don't think recreate is what I want as it recreates containers. It doesn't rebuild images (different thing).

Comment: One workaroung is to edit my Dockerfile until Docker realizes it needs to rebuild everything from scratch as a workaround.

Comment: Yes, `docker-compose` is old.  With a problematic Dockerfile I would use directly `docker build --no-cache` instead of `docker-compose` or even `docker compose`.

Comment: @Pino Thanks, that's a good idea! I didn't realize `docker build` does know the --no-cache flag! If you want, you can make that into an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

To clear the cache of a specific image and not all caches:

```
docker builder prune --filter "cache=true" --filter "label=key=value"
```

Or

```
docker builder prune --filter until=24h   #tested
```

But, for safety, make a test on the WSL, another PC to see the cache layers.

**Ref:** https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_prune/

Comment: "Invalid filter 'cache'", it tells me. Besides, it asks me to confirm "This will remove all dangling build cache". I want to remove all of it, dangling or not

Comment: I tried this: docker builder prune --filter until=24h, but please test on another PC to change hour..